# Asp.Net Localized SQL Content / How to define classes

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, localization

I have made a lot of research about this subject and now I am asking for some advices :)

I am working on a multilingual intranet. 
I am not talking about translating the UI (using resources etc..) but in translating the content.

I have several tables based on this format :

```
Product
-------------
IdProduct | DateCreation

ProductT
-------------
IdProduct | IdLanguage | ShortName

Question
-------------
IdQuestion | DateCreation

QuestionT
-------------
IdQuestion| IdLanguage | ShortName | Description

Language
-------------
IdLanguage | Culture
```

**My question is now :**

How to write the C# Classes for this Model. I am using Asp.Net MVC with a repository Pattern and Stored Procedures (No ORM like EF etc..) because we can't (not my decision)

For example for the Questions objects, I Will have to Display a correctly translated questions List in a page.
If the selected language version is not found for a question, display the English translation.

So how can I write down my classes to fit this need, and to be usable by my repositories, controllers and views

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your custom  [ResourceProviderFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.resourceproviderfactory.aspx). As example look at [ASP.NET 2.0 Custom SQL Server ResourceProvider](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14190/ASP-NET-2-0-Custom-SQL-Server-ResourceProvider). I use constant string with PK for accessing translation.

Comment: I specify in my post that I am not talking about translating the UI but getting the right translation of CONTENT. So this is not related to ResourceProvider